# Type deduction of forward_as_tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a ton of legacy code which contains objects which ultimately have to be serialised/deserialised. I ported most of this code already and can use some neat template features to do that nicely. Ultimately though, I'd love to be able to by reference pack all the parameters I need into a `std::tuple` and then do some generic seialisation/deserialisation. I managed that, however, I can't use `auto` to declare the type of my arg(ument)s I want to serialise:

```cpp
struct foo {
  int32_t var1 = 0;
  bool var2 = false;
  bool var3 = false;
  uint32_t var4 = 0x0;

  decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(var1, var2, var3, var4)) 
  args = std::forward_as_tuple(var1, var2, var3, var4);

  void serialize(uint8_t *out) const {
    SerializerWrapper::serializeTuple(out, args);
  }

  //legacy implementation just for comparison
  void serializeOld(uint8_t *out) const {
    uint32_t offset = 0;
    Serializer<int32_t>::serialize(out, offset,var1);
    Serializer<bool>::serialize(out, offset, var2);
    Serializer<bool>::serialize(out, offset, var3);
    Serializer<uint32_t>::serialize(out, offset, var4);
  }
  //..other stuff
}
```

Where the serialisation looks something like this:

```cpp
class SerializerWrapper {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    static void serialize(uint8_t* data, uint32_t& offset, const T& value) {
        Serializer<T>::serialize(data, offset, value); //These exist in the legacy code
    }
    //Serialistion of tuples
    template <typename TupleT, std::size_t... Is>
    static void serializeTupleIx(uint8_t* data, uint32_t& offset, const TupleT& tp, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        (serialize(data, offset, std::get<Is>(tp)), ...);
    }
    template <typename TupleT, std::size_t TupSize = std::tuple_size_v<TupleT>>
    static void serializeTuple(uint8_t* data, const TupleT& tp) {
        uint32_t offset = 0;
        serializeTupleIx(data, offset, tp, std::make_index_sequence<TupSize>{});
    }
//... more stuff (size, deserialisation, etc.)
}
```

Is there any nice way in C++17 to get rid of that ugly `decltype`?

Cheers and thanks

Edit: so, if I try to implement a `auto as_tuple() { return std::tie(a,b,c); }` I face the following problem:

```cpp
struct foo {
   //a,b,c etc.
    constexpr auto as_tuple() {
        return std::tie(a, b, c);
    }
    constexpr auto as_tuple() const {
        return std::tie(a, b, c);
    }
    void method_const() const {
        as_tuple();
    }
    void method_unconst() {
        as_tuple();
    }
};
```

The problem is that `serialize` and `size` are both `const`, as they push the object into the output stream. The `deserialize` takes the stream and "fills" the object, so it can't be `const`.

Comment: Personally I would create a function like `as_tuple` and then in the function have `auto as_tuple() { return std::tie(names, of, variables); }` and then when you need the tuple you just call `as_tuple()`.

Comment: Without true reflection, serialization is still a pain to do generically in C++. What you have is fine, and so is what @NathanOliver suggested. Otherwise, you'll need to lean on code generators (like macros and Boost MPL)

Comment: `as_tuple` is really better, your class has no extra member (especially with references which makes some special members "problematic" (copy constructor)).

Comment: I like the `as_tuple()` idea, but now I'm facing the problem of `as_tupel()` and `as_tuple() const`. I'll add it to the original post.